# Best way to correlate weights to nodes (Use a graph?)

Tags: database, algorithm, graph-theory, graph-databases

I don't have a strong software engineering background and I am currently tasked with correlating fuzzy hashes (Nilsimsa) and their similarity to one another. For example: I have a ton of strings ( Hundreds of thousands), I hash each one using Nilsimsa and then want to be able to correlate each hash to a similar hash (indicating a similar string)

I've been trying to think of the best way to go about this in a way that can scale (ultimately will need to be able to handle millions of strings input per day) I was thinking maybe a graph database or just a graph in general where the weights in between each node would be the similarity of the Nilsimsa hashes.

Im not asking anyone to implement anything just ideas or suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)?

Comment: [ScaNN](https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/07/announcing-scann-efficient-vector.html) has support for Hamming distance, which is what you need here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions looking into them now! @DavidEisenstat